# Display dates between two dates

Tags: php

I have a form that the user should fill two dates.I want to display dates between those selected dates like

```
  June 11
  June 12
  June 13
  June 14
  June 15
  Jun  16
  Jun  17
```

in my action.php

```
$dateTo = $r->getParameter("date_to", date('Y-m-d'));
$dateFrom = $r->getParameter("date_from", date('Y-m-d', strtotime('7 days ago', strtotime($dateTo))));

$dateRange = new DatePeriod(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$dateTo), new DateInterval('P1D'), DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$dateFrom));
```

then in my templates, I tried

```
foreach $dateRange as $date {echo $date}
```

Whats the correct way to display those date?
var_dump outputs like

```
 object(DatePeriod)[62]
 public 'start' => 
 object(DateTime)[21645]
  public 'date' => string '2015-05-20 16:56:21' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Asia/Manila' (length=11)
 public 'current' => null
 public 'end' => 
 object(DateTime)[21656]
```

and I tried

```
<?php foreach($dateRange as $r):?>
<?php echo $r->format('Y-m-d') ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

But nothing displayed in my table

Comment: What is the error you get ? What's the output you get ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP doc `DatePeriod` implements the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface. So you can use it like an array and loop with a foeeach over it:

```
/** @var DateTime[] $dateRange */
$dateRange = new DatePeriod(...);

foreach($dateRange as $date) {
    $date->format(...);
}
```

What is not mentioned in the official PHP doc is that you get an "array" of `DateTime` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `format`.
Like this:

`echo $date->format("Ymd") . "<br>";`